# split method for text value in Appcelerator

Tags: java, text, split, label, appcelerator-mobile

I have a window that displays my tweets in a label.

My tweets come from my FB page statuses and if i have put a pic or write more than 140 characters then i get a link in tweet to the actuall post.

I wonder if there is any way to get the label text to split so i can point the link into an url to open in webview

This is how far i have got:

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

win.showNavBar();

        var  desc = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: win.data,
        font:{
            fontSize:'20dp',
        fontWeight:'bold'
    },
    height:'300dp',
    left:'5dp',
    top:'10dp',
    color:'#111',
    touchEnabled:true
    });


  win.add(desc);


        desc.addEventListener('click',function(e){
var v = desc.text;

if(v.indexOf('http') != -1){
    // open new window with webview
    var tubeWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({ 
    modal: true,
    barColor: '#050505',
    backgroundColor: '#050505' 
}); 
    var linkview = Ti.UI.createWebView({
            url:  e.v,
            barColor: '#050505',
            backgroundColor: '#050505'              
        });
        // Create a button to close the modal window
var close_modal = Titanium.UI.createButton({title:'Stäng'});
tubeWindow.rightNavButton = close_modal;

// Handle close_modal event
close_modal.addEventListener('click', function() {
    tubeWindow.close();
});
 tubeWindow.add(linkview);
tubeWindow.open({
     modalTransitionStyle: Ti.UI.iPhone.MODAL_TRANSITION_STYLE_FLIP_HORIZONTAL,
});

}
});
win.open();
```

What i´ve been told i need to split the win.data to get the link. (win.data is the tweet)

now i just have:  url: e.v,  i need to get the link out

Any ideas on how this can work?

Thanx

//R

Comment: did my answer help? other people may be interested in this if so, up vote it / mark top answer or add a comment saying whats wrong so others can benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing a while ago. pull down the tweet(s) run the text through a regular expression to pull out a URL.

What I did was put each tweet in a tableview row, and set the tableview row to hasChild=true if the regular expression returned anything, then onClick of a tableView row, if hasChild == true open a webview with the given URL (stored in the row).

A regualr expression like the one here should work:
http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/view2D3B0109-C1B2-4B4E-BFFD-E8088CBC85FD.htm

So something like:

```
str= <<tweet text>>;
re= <<URL expression>>;

check=str.match(re);
```

now check contains either null or a url.